# R: subset dataframe based on column entry in multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe with information on several genes in a format similar to:

```
chr    start    end    Gene    Region
1    100    110    Bat     Exon
1    120    130    Bat     Intron
1    500    550    Ball    Upstream, Downstream
1    590    600    Ball    Intron, Upstream
1    900    980    Mit     Promoter, Upstream
```

I would like to subset the data to remove any rows that contains genes that have "Exon" or "Promoter" in the Regions column. I had been using:

```
Regions <- subset(Table, Region == "Intron" | Region== "DownStream" | Region =="Upstream" | Region=="DownStream,Upstream")
```

However this gives me:

```
chr    start    end    Gene    Region
1    120    130    Bat     Intron
1    500    550    Ball    Upstream, Downstream
1    590    600    Ball    Intron, Upstream
```

What I want is:

```
chr    start    end    Gene    Region
1    500    550    Ball    Upstream, Downstream
1    590    600    Ball    Intron, Upstream
```

Comment: Why do you want row 2 removed (with "Intron" in the region column)?

Comment: Each row refers to a changed location in a Gene. I don't want to see changes due to promoters or exons and would like to remove all genes that have any changes in those regions.

Comment: See my updated answer - is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using `grepl`:

```
df[!grepl("Exon|Promoter", df$Region),]
#  chr start end Gene               Region
#2   1   120 130  Bat               Intron
#3   1   500 550 Ball Upstream, Downstream
#4   1   590 600 Ball     Intron, Upstream
```

It's not clear to me why you want the row 2 with "Intron" removed as well. Please explain that.

#### Edit:

Think I understood now, try this instead:

```
temp <- df$Gene[grepl("Exon|Promoter", df$Region)]
df[!df$Gene %in% temp,]
#  chr start end Gene               Region
#3   1   500 550 Ball Upstream, Downstream
#4   1   590 600 Ball     Intron, Upstream
```